# Programmatically highlight option in select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using [select2 v4.0.2](https://select2.github.io/) to create a multi-select control that has selectable "groups" (I'm using `option` elements in place of `optgroup` since the latter is, by definition, not selectable). So, for example, if I have a group named *Fruit* and options under it are *Apple* and *Orange*, selecting the *Fruit* group item will auto-select the items beneath it. This part I have working successfully.

What I would like to do, however, is to highlight the "parent" option in the drop-down menu (i.e. it should have a gray "selected" background) when all of its children are selected. Here's a screenshot showing how things work now (I clicked the **Fruit** option to get the control into this state):

[image: Screenshot of select2 control]

In the drop-down menu, note that both Apple and Orange are selected. These items also appear in the box above, just as I would expect. What I would like to have happen is for the Fruit option to have a gray background in the dropdown (making it look as though it were selected), *without* appearing in the box above. Something like this mockup:

[image: Mockup of what I'd like to do]

Note that the difference in this screenshot is the highlighted background of the "parent" item. I'm aware that the `aria-selected` attribute is what's driving the background color styling, but I can't seem to toggle it on that particular list entry. I've tried doing this via handling the `select2:open` event, as well as through the `templateResult` function, and neither have worked.

Is there a way that I can fake out the selected-ness of the parent item in the dropdown list, without the parent item showing up in the box above?

My current code follows:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-select").select2({
    "multiple": true,
    "templateResult": function(data) {
      if(!data.element)
        return data.text;

      var $element = $(data.element);
      var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
      $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);
      $wrapper.text(data.text);
      return $wrapper;
    }
  }).on("select2:open", function(e) {
    var curVal = $(this).val();
    var target = e.target;

    for(var i=0; i<target.children.length; i++) {
      var child = target.children[i];
      var kidlist = $(child).attr("data-kids");
      if(kidlist) {
        var kids = $(child).attr("data-kids").split(',');
        var count = 0;
        for(var j=0; j<kids.length; j++) {
          if(curVal && curVal.indexOf(kids[j]) != -1)
            count += 1;
        }

        if(count == kids.length) {
          // This doesn't work!!!
          var results = $("#select2-my-select-results");
          $(results[0].children[i]).attr("aria-selected", true);
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .on("select2:select", function(e) {
    var curVal = $(this).val();
    var el = e.params.data.element;
    var myval = $(el).val();
    var kids = $(el).attr("data-kids");
    if(kids) {
      var pieces = kids.split(',');
      var numKidsSelected = 0;
      for(var i=0; i<pieces.length; i++) {
        if(curVal.indexOf(pieces[i]) != -1) {
          numKidsSelected += 1;
        }
      }

      var notKids = [];
      for(var i=0; i<curVal.length; i++) {
        if(pieces.indexOf(curVal[i]) == -1 &&
           curVal[i] != myval) {
          notKids.push(curVal[i]);
        }
      }

      if(numKidsSelected == pieces.length) {
        $(this).val(notKids).trigger("change"); // Remove the kids
      } else {
        $(this).val(notKids.concat(pieces)).trigger("change");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="my_select" id="my-select" multiple="multiple"
    data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="All Items">
    <option value="1" class="bold" data-kids="2,3">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2" class="indent">Apple</option>
    <option value="3" class="indent">Orange</option>
    <option value="4" class="bold" data-kids="5,6">Vegetable</option>
    <option value="5" class="indent">Green Bean</option>
    <option value="6" class="indent">Potato</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So if Orange is highlighted, you want Fruit to be highlighted?

Comment: Both Apple and Orange are already selected in the example screenshot. I'd like for the parent item to also be selected. Ideally, it would only be selected in the case where all children are selected, but I can't figure out how to select the parent at all and not have it appear in the list of items above the pulldown.

Comment: You're saying if you click Fruit, it will list Fruit, Apple, Orange?

Comment: If I click Fruit, only Apple and Orange will be listed in the box above. However, I want all three to be highlighted in the dropdown if possible.

Comment: You're confusing me, that's different from `Is there a way that I can fake out the selected-ness of the parent item, without the parent item showing up in the list?`

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I've updated the question text, hopefully making things clearer. Also added another screenshot.

Comment: You can do it this way, compare the list and the children in the particular `optgroup`, if they match, simply change the background-color for `optgroup`. Notice it is a good idea to bind an event to this, so that when items from the optgroup get removed, so will the background.